# Disable and re-enable all indexes in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am running a DTS to preform tasks in my database, in which at first I need to disable **all** indexes in the database and re-enable them when the DTS finish his work.

Is there a way that I can disable all the indexes in the whole database and afterwards to re-enable them all?

I know how to disable/enable one by one, can someone help me with the way to disable/enable **all** at once as a step in the DTS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable all non-clustered indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518125/disable-all-non-clustered-indexes)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is a script that will output ALTER statements for all non clustered indexes in your database. You can modify this easily to output REBUILD scripts and scripts for clustered indexes

```
select 'ALTER INDEX [' + I.name + '] ON [' + T.name + '] DISABLE' 
from sys.indexes I
inner join sys.tables T on I.object_id = T.object_id
where I.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED'
and I.name is not null
```

Comment: You probably meant REBUILD rather than ENABLE?

Answer (score 59):

We can use below scrip to disable indexes

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [TableName]
DISABLE;
```

Do your bulk insert to table and than run below script.

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [TableName]
REBUILD;
```

Comment: The question read: *"Disable and re-enable all indexes in a SQL Server database"*. Not for a single table, for the whole database.

Comment: This should be: "ALTER INDEX ALL ON StorageItem REBUILD;" not "ALTER INDEX ALL ON StorageItem ENABLE;"

Comment: It doesn't answer OP's problem completely, but I like it, it's helpful too.

Comment: This is simple and effective, but for anyone arriving at this thread wanting to do a conditional bulk update or delete (like me) this will disable your primary key and crush your performance. You probably want to disable only non-clustered indexes and depending on your conditions you might be better off keeping some of the non-clustered indexes active as well.

Comment: This can also be done from SQLStudio, go to "Indexes" and use the context menu.

Answer (score 34):

This works for SQL Server 2008 and newer versions. It allows different schemas and also names that have spaces, dashes and other special characters that have to be quoted. [What is the use of the square brackets [] in sql statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-use-of-the-square-brackets-in-sql-statements)

These scripts will output code into the results tab.  You must copy/paste into the query tab and execute them.

Disable script

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(I.name) + ' ON ' +  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id))+'.'+ QUOTENAME(T.name) + ' DISABLE' 
FROM sys.indexes I
INNER JOIN sys.tables T ON I.object_id = T.object_id
WHERE I.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED'
AND I.name IS NOT NULL
AND I.is_disabled = 0
```

Enable script (Rebuild)

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(I.name) + ' ON ' +  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(T.schema_id))+'.'+ QUOTENAME(T.name) + ' REBUILD' 
FROM sys.indexes I
INNER JOIN sys.tables T ON I.object_id = T.object_id
WHERE I.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED'
AND I.name IS NOT NULL
AND I.is_disabled = 1
```

This is based on another answer here.

Comment: Appreciate the added SCHEMA part!

Answer (score 6):

In order to enable an index, you have to rebuild it. This script will rebuild all disabled indexes.

```
DECLARE @my_sql2 NVARCHAR(200);

DECLARE cur_rebuild CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' +  i.name + ' ON ' + t.name + ' REBUILD' FROM sys.indexes i JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id WHERE i.is_disabled = 1 ORDER BY t.name, i.name;
OPEN cur_rebuild;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_rebuild INTO @my_sql2;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      EXECUTE sp_executesql  @my_sql2;
      FETCH NEXT FROM cur_rebuild INTO @my_sql2;
   END;
CLOSE cur_rebuild;
DEALLOCATE cur_rebuild;
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this script to disable all indices

```
-- Disable All Indices
DECLARE @Script NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE curIndices CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(indices.name) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(tableNames.schema_id))+'.'+ QUOTENAME(tableNames.name) + ' DISABLE'
    FROM
        sys.indexes indices  INNER JOIN 
        sys.tables tableNames ON indices.object_id = tableNames.object_id
    WHERE 
        indices.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED' AND 
        indices.name IS NOT NULL AND
        indices.is_disabled = 0;
OPEN curIndices
FETCH NEXT FROM curIndices INTO @Script
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @Script
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Script 

    FETCH NEXT FROM curIndices INTO @Script
END
CLOSE curIndices
DEALLOCATE curIndices
```

Use this script to rebuild(enable) all indices

```
-- Rebuild All Indices
DECLARE @Script NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE curIndices CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(indices.name) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(tableNames.schema_id))+'.'+ QUOTENAME(tableNames.name) + ' REBUILD'
    FROM
        sys.indexes indices  INNER JOIN 
        sys.tables tableNames ON indices.object_id = tableNames.object_id
    WHERE 
        indices.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED' AND 
        indices.name IS NOT NULL AND
        indices.is_disabled = 1;
OPEN curIndices
FETCH NEXT FROM curIndices INTO @Script
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @Script
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Script 

    FETCH NEXT FROM curIndices INTO @Script
END
CLOSE curIndices
DEALLOCATE curIndices
```

Comment: Amazing, works fantastic and no need to run a script to generate another script, briljant!

Answer (score 3):

Disabling indexes is a good idea when it comes to loading large quantities of data, but... the big problem is clustered indexes. If you disable a clustered index, you’ve disabled the entire table.

Several options suggest themselves, and none of them are simple.

1) Loop through the system views (sys.indexes), extract the table and index name, generate and execute dynamic SQL to disable the index. Have an “undo” routine to re-enable them. (Be wary--was it a unique index or a unique constraint?) This, alas, only works if you do not use clustered indexes. Good luck with that.

2) As for 1, but skip any clustered indexes. When you load data, make sure it gets loaded in (clustered index) sequential order, otherwise you'll have poor load times and fragmented tables. (If you data providers are like mine, good luck with that one, too.)

3) Create tables in your database containing definitions of the indexes on your “loading” tables. Build a routine that loops through them and **drops** all the indexes (clustered indexes last). This will be fast if you truncate the tables first. Load your data, then loop through and recreate the indexes from scratch (clustered first). Use table partitioning to make less horrible on the rest of the system (e.g. do all the above on the “loading” tables, then use partition switching to move the loaded data into your “live” tables). It took me no little time to build such a system, but it can and will work.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting DBCC CHECKDB consistency errors after re-enabling indexes, before realizing that clustered should go first.

Comment: you can also enable indexes using SQL Server Management Studio see here: http://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/enable-and-disable-indexes/

Answer (score 2):

You will have to run a script that selects the metadate for the table and index.  Then you can do an:

```
ALTER INDEX indexname ON tablename DISABLE;
```

Later you can run a similar script to rebuild:

```
ALTER INDEX indexname ON tablename REBUILD;
```

You can do these one at a time, or collect them into a NVARCHAR(MAX) variable and execute them as a single batch.  You can see sample code at this earlier question:

[Disable all non-clustered indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518125/disable-all-non-clustered-indexes)

Comment: Literally from the TS: "I know how to disable/enable one by one, can someone help me with the way to disable/enable all at once"

Answer (score 0):

1. Disble all index first:  ALTER INDEX ALL ON tablename DISABLE;
2. Enable clustered index first: ALTER INDEX column_name(clustered index) ON tablename REBUILD; otherwise error will
3. Enable all index now : ALTER INDEX ALL ON tablename REBUILD;

All the index will be enabled by charm!